# SQL - What clauses do ESCAPE characters work in?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to make an SQL view where some columns would have special characters in them.

```
    #Hours  EmployeeID
    3       12D
    4       E44
```

I tried to use something like this...

```
CREATE VIEW rollCall AS
    SELECT (hourStart - hourEnd) AS ##Hours ESCAPE '#'
        , employeeID
    FROM Employee;

SELECT * FROM rollCall;
```

But for some reason I'm getting an error that said it expected a right parenthesis when AS came up. I'm confused about what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you against doing this.  But you need to escape the name:

```
CREATE VIEW rollCall AS
    SELECT (hourStart - hourEnd) AS "##Hours", 
           employeeID
    FROM Employee;
```

I only associate `ESCAPE` with `LIKE`, although it is perhaps used in some other clauses.